# Laravel relation return model id insetead of the model itself

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Consider this relation:

```
// in Post model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

I think `$post->user->name` should be enough to get the name of post's owner. However `$post->user` return the user id instead of the user model. So I have to use:

```
$post->user()->first()->name;
```

Shouldn't `$post->user` return the post's owner?

Comment: Your relation isn't right. Your Post belongs to a User, right? So it should be `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');`

Comment: @StuartWagner Thanks, it was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

Does a user belong to a post or does a post belong to a user?

From my perspective, a user has many posts, and a post belongs to a user. So I think you have messed up your relations.

```
class Post extends Model
{
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }
}

class User extends Model
{
  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
  }
}
```

Then, once you have a Post, you will be able to access it's user.

`$userName = Post::find(1)->user->name;`

Comment: This does not work for me. `Post::find(1)->user` returns the user id not model. –  PHPst 11 hours ago

Comment: @PHPst - This should work. Please provide your `Post` model and `User` Model. Please also provide your schema for `posts` and `users`. Also, do you have a `user_id` field on the `posts` table? 

Finally, if `Post::find(1)->user` is returning an id, then this means that the foreign key on your `posts` table might be `user` which stores id? If this is the case, then your table/column naming conventions is not best practice.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the foreign key on your posts table is  `user` which stores `id`. This style is really comfortable for me. How to make it work with Laravel? Does Laravel has any recommendation regarding naming foreign keys?

Comment: @PHPst - Dont think about Laravel specific recommendations. Think about architecting your database and choose standard / logical table naming conventions. e.g. The table which holds posts, could be named `posts`. Your table which contains users could be names `users`. If a post is written by a user, then on your `posts` table, you could have a `user_id` column which would be the foreign key referencing your primary key `id` on the `users` table.